# Is the Xbox One controller compatible with Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

I simply do not have the finances available to test this out yet, so I am requesting help from someone who has the answer. I am aware of the original Xbox controller [is not compatible with the 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_Controller), but does this hold true for the Xbox One controller on the 360?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Xbox One controller WILL NOT work with the 360. I have both consoles and have tested. **Microsoft** stated that the controller shall not work on 360. **Meaning Xbox One controller works only with Xbox One** and **360 controller works with/only 360 console**.

But PS4 Dualshock controller works on 360 not sure about Xbox One though.

[Cited](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360)

Comment: "*Microsoft It self stated that the controller shall not work on 360.*" Could you link to a source?

Comment: They said it E3, no link's so far. But I think IGN even made a video about it.

Comment: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360 now cited

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to that might work (I haven't tested) on the [xbox support website](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360) they state that you can plug your xbox 360 into your xbox one through the **HDMI IN** slot

> If you want to access your Xbox 360 console, you can plug your Xbox 360 into the Xbox One through the Xbox One’s HDMI In port.

This should in theory allow you to use your xbox one controller on your 360 console through the xbox one console. It's a bit weird since I don't know why you would want to do this except for possible controller compatibility. It also states that if you turn of the 360s kinect you will be able to use the xbox one kinect with your 360 through your xbox one. I believe it acts like the TV App on the xbox one console. There have been reports that this could cause lack when playing games - as I said I haven't tested this. This is all based on what has come of the [Microsoft xbox one support site](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360)

Comment: Nops. It can't work. XBOX one can't sent back the signals to xbox 360. Even if it can (which it can't", HDMI won't be compatible to send the signals.

So, It can never work.

Comment: The article on the website is just describing how to view the output of your 360 through the Xbox One, Its not about controllers.

I believe you can't do this video passthrough on the S, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

No - you must use the Xbox 360 controller with the Xbox360 hooked up to the Xbox one. I've tried it.